# ASP:Content master page control being called when not in markup?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, layout, master-pages

I'm using an ASP master page to lay out content on my webpage.

The Site.Master file looks something like this.

```
   <div class="container fullwidth-main-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FullWidthMainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="container margin-main-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MarginMainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

Now.. On my default.aspx I'm calling the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FullWidthMainContent" control.` amongst other content controls.

However on my Portfolio.aspx page for some reason even though I'm not calling the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FullWidthMainContent" control` it's still appearing underneith my other content that I have called.

Why is this happening?